# displaying response codes per error code

Tags: jquery, ajax

What i'm trying to get this to do is to display different error messages, response code `200`, `400`, `404`, `408` & `500` however, i don't think i'm do it right.

i looked at this one: [jQuery AJAX Error Handling (HTTP Status Codes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12734714/jquery-ajax-error-handling-http-status-codes) but was still confused..

What i have below is probably messy, but any guidance?

```
            var request;  //make request object a global variable
            function getAJAX(){
              request = new XMLHttpRequest();
              request.open("GET", "file.txt");
              request.onreadystatechange = checkData;
              request.send(null);
            } // end function\

            function getYo(){
              request = new XMLHttpRequest();
              request.open("GET", "file2.txt");
              request.onreadystatechange = checkDataa;
              request.send(null);
            } // end function

            function checkData(){
              if (request.readyState == 4) {
                // if state is finished
                if (request.status == 200) {
                  // and if attempt was successful
                  alert(request.responseText);
                } // end if
              } // end if
            } // end checkData

            function checkDataa(){
              if (request.readyState == 4) {
                // if state is finished
                if (request.status == 400) {
                  // and if attempt was successful
                  alert(request.responseText);
                } // end if
              } // end if
            } // end checkData
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? what is the use of these functions? where and how do you use it in your code? where are you sending it to? please clarify!

Comment: Are you trying to code this is pure javascript or are you using the jQuery framework?

Comment: i have this in html form. `<button type="button" onclick="getAJAX()">1</button>`
  `<button type="button" onclick="getYo()">2</button>`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple function to use within both and pass in the status ( and anything else you may want):

```
function errorAlert( status ){
   var msg;
   switch(status}{
      case 404:
         msg  = "Ooooops can't find it!";
       break;
       default:
          msg = 'unknown error';
   }
   alert( msg );
}
```

Then in your request callback

```
if (request.readyState == 4) {
   if( request.status !== 200){
         errorAlert(  request.status );
         /* quit here */
         return;
   }
    /* handle response here */
}
```

This is obviously fairly primitive but should give you an idea how to build on it

Answer (score 0):

Utilizing jquery `$.ajax()` `statusCode` settings object , callback function , try

Edit, updated

html , e.g.,

```
<button id="error">error</button>
<button id="success">success</button>
```

js

```
$(function() {
    var urls = ["file.txt", "file1.txt"];
    var request = function (url) {
        return $.ajax({
        url : url, 
        type : "GET",
        statusCode : {
            200 : function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
                    alert(data);
            },
            403 : function (jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus + "\n" + errorThrown);
            },
            404 : function (jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus + "\n" + errorThrown);
            }
        }
    });
    };

$("button#error").on("click", function(e) {
    request(urls[0]);
});
$("button#success").on("click", function(e) {
    request(urls[1]);
});

});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/XSQ3w/

Comment: So for my inputs, how would i call the `onclick="name()"` ?