# How to retrieve data, when jqxhr get 304 response

Tags: jquery, ajax, jqxhr, http-status-code-304

I am creating an ajax request, where I get some data returned from server with 200 OK response code.

The request header uses if-modified-since to get a 304. My question is that when there is a 304 response, the data is not available in jqxhr responseText, it is empty and I understand why it should be empty (because data should be in browser cache already. Right? ).

My query is how can I retrieve that data when I got a 304 from server?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24814418/displaying-response-codes-per-error-code/